# Test if Attribute = Node Value without Using Variables

Tags: xml, variables, xslt

Ive got this XML file

```
<all>
 <general>
  <catagory_name>
   <catg>Action</catg_1>
   <catg>Other</catg_2>
  </catagory_name>
 </general>
 <games>
  <catagory name='Action'>
   <game>
    <name>1945<!--name--></name>
    <url><!--URL to game download--></url>
    <image><!--image location--></image>
    <alt>1945 Icon<!--alt text for image--></alt>
   </game>
  </catagory>
  <catagory name='Other'>
   <game>
    <name>Platform Game<!--name--></name>
    <url><!--URL to game download--></url>
    <image><!--image location--></image>
    <alt>Platform Game Icon<!--alt text for image--></alt>
   </game>
  </catagory>
 </games>
</all>
```

At the moment my an extract from my xslt reads

```
<xsl:for-each select="all/general/catagory_name">
<xsl:variable name="catg"><xsl:value-of select="catg"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:if test="//all/games/catagory[@name=$catg]/game[position() = (1<!--I use nth term here but this is not relevant to my question so just pretend value = 1-->)]/url">
<!--action-->
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want to know how to replace [@name=$catg] with the value of //all/general/catagory_name/catg_1 but can't work out how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know how to replace `[@name=$catg]` with the value of
>   `//all/general/catagory_name/catg_1` but can't work out how to.

**Use**:

```
/all/games/catagory[@name = current()/catg1]
```

This selects all `/all/games/catagory` elements the string value of whose `name` attribute is equal to the string value of one (in this specific case exactly one) `catg1` children of the currently matched (or currently executed upon by `xsl:for-each`) element.

**Read more about the XSLT [`current()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current) function in the W3C XSLT 1.0 specification**.

Comment: thumbs up! I was about to type same answer :) `Current()` is significant here :)

Comment: @infantprogrammer'Aravind': Absolutely -- be aware it is `current()` . Xml/XPath/XSLT is case-sensitive.

Comment: thank you very very much this has just finnished my code for me